# Why can't I run this fibonacci sequence?

Tags: python

extremely new to python, whenever I try to run this code

```
def fib(n):
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end = ' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()
```

I get an error message saying either 
`print(a, end=' ') SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
or
`fib() not defined`.
how can I solve this?

Comment: Use `python3` to run your code instead of `python` or `python2`.

Comment: Yes @rhizome it is working in python3

Comment: How are you able to get one error **or** another? Include details how you run this, so we can replicate your problem(s).

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't take value of `n` from the user.

```py
def fib(n):
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end = ' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()
fib(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no issue if you were to use Python 3 so consider using that instead.

If you like python2 a lot then modify your code to the following:

```
def fib(n):
"""Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
a, b = 0, 1
while a < n:
    print(str(a) + ' ')
    a, b = b, a+b
```

This is because python2 doesn't allow the use of

```
print(a, end = ' ')
```

It is a python3 feature